# How do I add nested categories to drop-down menu in twenty-eleven?

Tags: menus, themes, theme-twenty-eleven

I know how to do it by writing a separate ul/li css for wp_list_categories, but I find menus of "twenty eleven" already well designed and flexible, so I`d like to use them. 
Custom menus, when I have to add subcategories manually, are not a solution, sinse I will allow my users to create new categories. What would you do?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4325/12615) two [links](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-modify-lists-like-categories-and-blogroll-in-wordpress) can help to find an answer... Looks like extending the Category Walker is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As a purely theory example, this is how I would approach the problem:

```
$cats = get_categories();
echo '<ul>';
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    echo'<li>'.$cat->name;
    if($cat->parent != 0) {
       $subcats = get_category('child_of='.$cat->cat_ID;
       echo '<ul>';
       foreach($subcats as $subcat){
        echo '<li>'.$subcat->name.'</li>';
       }
    }
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

I don't expect that to work fully as I coded it there based of [this codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) but I am fairly certain that my theory is correct. I may have the `$cat->parent` backwards though...

Comment: If I get it right, this solution replaces the convenient menus system, instead of adding categories to it? I have used something like that, and I have used plugins that do it. But all these options mean killing current flexibility of menus, so if you want to add a page or link or anything later, you have to code again, instead of just editing custom menus in backend.

Comment: If you want to add the link, you will need to do this `echo <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'">'.$cat->name.'</a>';` I use code similar to this on one of my sites to generate a category based menu. Just add css classes and she'll be right.

Comment: Yeah, this is very similar to my current solution. Thank you for efforts, but I guess you miss the point: to retain the comfort of controlling menus from backend.

Comment: For pages and so forth? there is an argument you can post to the $args array that orders by the `menu` tab.